# Multithreading -How should you initialize variables without using the volatile keyword constantly

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I'm creating a game using java and at one point I create a thread to initialize a class that initializes other classes etc. After I do that and the thread is not active, my main thread accesses the class I initialized and calls a method that uses variables initialized using the other thread which then calls another class's methods which has variables initialized by the other thread etc.

My question is, if I want to initialize a lot of variables using a separate thread that are in a bunch of different classes, do I need to make all the variables that I initialize volatile or is there a better way so that all the variables I initialize using that one thread are automatically accessible by other threads.

This question isn't should I use the volatile keyword it's more or a, should I not use the volatile keyword and is there a better option that making a lot of my variables volatile.

Also, if it helps, my program has an object oriented structure.

Comment: Why would you use a separate thread to initialize variables?

Comment: The data that I'm initializing takes a little bit of time to load and I want the program to render a few different things while it's loading kind of like a loading screen except it doesn't take that long.

Comment: No, you shouldn't make all your variables volatile. You might want to create a separate thread for the loading screen animation instead, and when the initialization is ready just stop that thread and continue on normally. Now you've got it a bit backwards.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused as to the use of the `volatile` keyword. You don't use the `volatile` keyword to make variables visible to other threads. `volatile` is used to establish a happens-before relationship between writes to a variable and subsequent reads of that variable. This is accomplished by forcing the variable to be read from main memory each time it is read rather than allowing the variable to be read from a CPU cache.

You don't need to do anything special to make an object or elements of an object visible to other threads.

Comment: *"You don't use the volatile keyword to make variables visible to other threads."* ... as it happens, that is exactly the reason why you use the `volatile` keyword.  The `volatile` modifier provides a weak form of thread safety by providing visibility, but by itself provides nothing for atomicity or mutual exclusion ... and, so, `volatile` is actually unable to guarantee a happens-before relationship when object state is comprised by more than a single field.

Comment: *"You don't need to do anything special to make an object or elements of an object visible to other threads."* ... this is irretrievably and inarguably false.

Comment: @scottb `volatile` does not provide visibility of a field to other threads. It provides visibility of _changes_ to that variable to other threads. Can you provide a link to back up what you're saying here?

Comment: I disagree.  The `volatile` keyword provides visibility.  It assures that all threads will read the same value from a field irrespective of when or even if the field's value has changed.  This is straight from Chapter 9, "Concurrency" in Effective Java, 2nd Ed.  J. Bloch.

Comment: I can't find anything to support what you're saying in that book.  Page 262 says "While the `volatile` modifier performs no mutual exclusion, it guarantees that any thread that reads the field will see the most recently written value," which seems to support what I'm saying. Can you point me to the part of the book that you're referencing?

Comment: How is what you've directly quoted from item 66 different than what I wrote above: "It assures that all threads will read the same value from a field irrespective of when or even if the field's value has changed." In other words, it guarantees that the most recently written value is **visible to all threads.** Maybe you are confusing visibility here with accessibility.

Comment: JLS 17.4.5: "Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible [...] A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field."

Comment: @scottb I think we might be saying the same thing here, but in different ways.

Comment: I'd agree, but I still cannot agree that *"`volatile` does not provide visibility of a field to other threads"* is correct reasoning.  Visibility to other threads (without explicit synchronization) is precisely what it does.

Comment: It provides visibility _of the most recent changes_ to all threads. Not visibility/accessibility of the field itself, which is how I believed the OP was interpreting it. But yeah. I think we're on the same page lol